# mysql query to match multiple words and display result using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull data using an mysql query that requires that I look for keywords within a field in the database.

A user in my database may have the following in their 'subjects' field:

'math | science | reading | writing'

This means that user accepts all of those subjects.  This table is called 'user_teacher'

I have another table for students (called 'student_requests') that consists of requests from students for say, science, or math, or maybe even two subjects (so the entry in this case would look like 'science | math').  This table stores those values also in a field called 'subjects'.

My question is, how would I form a query where i am looking up entries in 'student_requests' where the subject matches any of the listed subjects within a particular user's profile from the table 'user_teacher'?  Let's assume that i originally look up the teacher's subject field using something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_teacher WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1 ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $teacher_subjects=$row->subject;
}
```

In other words, if i am a teacher who offers reading and math, i want to see all entries in the 'student_requests' table where the subject field has 'math' or 'reading' in it.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.  Also, if you think I am approaching this problem incorrectly based on how i have set up the tables, please let me know.  My goal here is to have the queries run as quickly as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try not using that kind of construction for you tables, instead make another table `subjects` (`id`, `name`) and other two tables `students_requests` (`id`, `id_student`, `id_subject`) [here you can record multiple requests for one student], and `teach_subjects` (`id`, `id_teach`, `suject_id`) [the same, multiple subject for a teacher] and yhen you can make a join, or even a plain php check between tables, based on what you received.

EDIT 1:

```
SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `subject_id` FROM `students_request` INTERSECT SELECT `subject_id` FROM `teach_subject`);
```

And please change `id_subject` from `students_requests` in `subject_id`.

Comment: will this method be faster performance wise than the solution proposed below by Dor Shemer?

Comment: @robmelino Yes, my version is the normalization of your system. check wikipedia for 3 normal form.

Comment: assuming i had created the tables as you describe, could you include in your answer an example of what the join mysql query would look like?  Or alternatively the php check you suggested?  thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining `subjects` as a text field, try using `set`. Your definition should be along the lines of:

```
subjects SET('math', 'science', 'reading', 'writing')
```

Then you can search those fields in a more convenient way, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM student_requests s join user_teacher t ON (FIND_IN_SET(s.subject, t.subjects)>0) WHERE t.username = '$username';
```

That should give you all the students that requested subjects this teacher accepts.

Read more about sets here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html